# How to format text as a number using the Google Sheets API?

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet where info in column C is a number that is populated as a string.

**Example**: cell value is **'35135.22**.

In a browser I can highlight column C & select Format > Number > #,##0 and it will convert the string to an number and then format it. (example becomes 35,135)

When I attempt to do this using the Google Sheet API (and python) using batchUpdate and numberFormat it does not convert the string to a number.  It does format the cell, but because the cell value is still a string, the formatting is ignored.

How can I convert a string to a numerical value using the sheets api?

(I have this same issue with dates that are populated from my data source as a string)

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.  I was entering the data as RAW.  If I change:

*value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED'*

it works.

Comment: value_input_option = 'USER_ENTERED' this Does not worked for me. 
    value_input_option = 'UNFORMATTED_VALUE' Worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse it to float by this command (if you are talking about JavaScript API):

```
parseFloat(your_number_variable);
```

If you are asking for python solution it would be:

```
float(your_number_variable)
```

Please set the proper language tags next time when asking.

Comment: Thanks.  It will work to parse the numerical source data as a float (rather than a string) before writing to the Google Sheet in my Python script.  I am still not sure the best way to fix dates.  I get a "Object of type 'date' is not JSON serializable" error when not writing as a string.

Comment: try json_str = json.dumps(json, default=str)