# where to add the valueInputOption to enable formatting dates? (google sheets API)

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I have a python script that has to update a column in a google sheet to specific date format:

```
    req = [
          { 
            "repeatCell": {
              "range": {
                "sheetId": SHEET_ID,
                "startColumnIndex": 2,
                "endColumnIndex" : 3,
              },
              "cell": {
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  "numberFormat": {
                      "type": "DATE",
                      "pattern": "dd-mmm-yyyy"
                },
                  
                  "horizontalAlignment" : "CENTER",  #OPTIONS: 'LEFT', 'RIGHT', 'CENTER'
                }
              },
              "fields": "userEnteredFormat(numberFormat,horizontalAlignment)",
            }
          }]
        body = {'requests':req}
        sheet.batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID, body=body).execute()
```

However the updates don't go through.  I checked and from what I understand it is because the date format in the file is string (starts with ', like `'2021-03-06 14:19:17.102`.

I saw some answers that suggest that I have to change `ValueInputOption` to 'USER_ENTERED', but I cannot find where to add the change in the script?

eg: ([How to format text as a number using the Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51733735/how-to-format-text-as-a-number-using-the-google-sheets-api))

I tried adding `ValueInputOption='USER_ENTERED'` in last row, and i tried `body = {'requests':req, 'ValueInputOption':'USER_ENTERED'`.  Not sure where this change supposed to go?

Or is there another way to overwrite 'string' to date and number formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

The `ValueInputOption` parameter is from a different batchUpdate request, namely the `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate` method, and cannot be used in `spreadsheets.batchUpdate`.

Also, since the value of the cell forces the date to be a string value due to the `'`, you need to remove it either manually or via `spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate()`.

**References:**

[spreadsheets.batchUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)

[spreadsheets.values.batchUpdate()](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchUpdate)

Comment: Just realized that the value input option is from a different method altogether, you are trying to modify the structure of the sheet via spreadsheets.batchUpdate instead of modifying the values. I edited my explanation on the matter.